# Selenium Explicit waits not working properly in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I try to crawl the head banner carousel for practice in [python.org](https://www.python.org/). I use `WebDriverWait` to wait elements visible after clicking the trigger but not working properly. Here is my code.

```
# ChromeDriver
driver.get("https://www.python.org/")

hBannerNav = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//ol[@class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"]/li/a')

for i in range(len(hBannerNav)):
    print(hBannerNav[i].text)
    hBannerNav[i].click()
    try: 
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="slides menu"]/li[{}]'.format(i + 1))))
        h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//ul[@class="slides menu"]/li[{}]/div/h1'.format(i + 1))
        print(h1.text) 

        # if add a sleep the crawler will work properly and smoothly,
        # but I want to use WebDriverWait only.
        # sleep(1) 

    except Exception as e:
        print('error', e)
```

Here are logs:

```
# without sleep
1
Functions Defined
2
Compound Data Types
3
error Message:

4
Quick & Easy to Learn
5
All the Flow You’d Expect # wait for a long time but still crawl it

# use sleep
1
Functions Defined
2
Compound Data Types
3
Intuitive Interpretation
4
Quick & Easy to Learn
5
All the Flow You’d Expect
```

---

Use `presence_of_all_elements_located`

```
# the results by using 
h1 = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="slides menu"]/li[{}]/div/h1'.format(i + 1))))[0]

1
Functions Defined
2
Compound Data Types
3

4

5
```

Comment: I used presence_of_all_elements_located in my project and it worked fine for me. You might want to try it.

Comment: you can try adding a implicit wait, which will poll the dom to find the element till the time given. To do this once the driver is created add driver.implicitly_wait(time to wait in seconds)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual error. Try removing the `try/except` so you can see the full error.

Comment: @mblakesley It's a TimeoutException.

Comment: @kerwei It's not work for me and the results is updated on my post.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed. And also that additional piece of info that you gave @mblakesley. I just can't wrap my head around how text is printed if your 1s sleep comes after it

Comment: Okay, I just realized that you're targeting a carousel after loading up the page. The <li> element has their display set to None in a periodic manner so I think that is affecting your EC.visibility_of_element_located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I loaded up your code and gave it a whirl. You're essentially doing it right; the problem is this `slides menu` element is a little weird. When switching slides, there's a fade effect that takes a fraction of a second. During this time, the `li`/`h1` of interest is considered "visible" BUT the slide buttons are unresponsive! Try clicking them yourself during the fade effect. Nothing happens.

I often run into these small, unexpected timing problems when using Selenium, and the solution varies from case to case.

Normally I'd check if the buttons are clickable, but clickability is not the issue here.

Here, I got it to work by waiting for invisibility of the previous slide:

```
for i in range(len(hBannerNav)):
    print(hBannerNav[i].text)
    hBannerNav[i].click()
    # We don't wait if i == 0 because in that case, there's no previous slide
    if i > 0:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="slides menu"]/li[{}]'.format(i))))
    h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//ul[@class="slides menu"]/li[{}]/div/h1'.format(i + 1))
    print(h1.text)
```

There may be other, potentially better ways to get around this timing problem, but hopefully this is enough to get you unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

Add a second wait - for the `/div/h1`:

```
h1 = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="slides menu"]/li[{}]/div/h1'.format(i + 1))))
```

It m8ght be the case it's put in the html a bit later than its parent.

The [`WebdriverWait.until()`](https://github.com/browserstack/selenium-webdriver-python/blob/master/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py#L65) does return the matched element, so `h1` will have the desired value.

Comment: Looks good, though I don't think you need the first wait at all anymore.

Comment: It didn't work whether I kept both or left the second only. The results are the same.